# Is there an opposite for Dark Speech?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, alignment, languages

3.5e Book of vile darkness Page48 mentions dark Speech. In short, it's a language of the evil gods of pure vileness.

I was wondering if there is also a Good aligned variant of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *Book of Exalted Deeds* has the feat **Words of Creation** (48) that gives access to Words of Creation effects (31–2) that brightly mirror the Dark Speech effects described by the *Book of Vile Darkness* (32–3).

However, so far as I'm aware, there's no corresponding kinds of speech for chaos, law, or neutrality.

Comment: There very much *was* in OD&D.

Comment: @RobertColumbia You mean, like, [alignment languages](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/10032/8610)? Those were just means of communication; Dark Speech and Words of Creation, on the other hand, are, like, verbal superpowers: they break stuff and make stuff by speaking them at other stuff.